# what's the relationship between SDL and OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, sdl

Anyone can tell me what's the relationship between SDL library and OpenGL library?

Answer (score 4):

*OpenGL* is a graphics library that doesn't provide any feature in addition to drawing. It is neither able to embed an OpenGL view inside a window of any modern OS.

That's where *SDL* comes right into place and provides all the required functions needed to create an OpenGL window in a cross-platform manner in which you then draw by using OpenGL library itself. *SDL* also has a lot of facilities that are almost always necessary when working with games or graphical applications like timers, management of keyboard and mouse and whatever.

In any case you could use any other OpenGL wrapper like *GLUT* library or *GLFW* to achieve the same thing: creating an OpenGL view inside an application.

Comment: Actually OpenGL those days is a API to access the GPU dirvers and not so much a library that actually does something on most systems. The naming is purely historical. Otherwise you're right.